# xarray dataset not reading longitude/latitude data in a way I can subset

Tags: python-xarray

Hey so I am using NOAA weather data and I am trying to select longitude and latitude variables.

I simply want to make a variable called lat and lon that is equal to latitude and longitude values from the dataset. The latitude/longitude variables are not the same "type" as temperature based on the data when I print the dataset. (you can see in the photo). Is there any way to get that "type" of data to be equal to the temperature/time data in that dataset? [image]

I am sorry for being bad at explaining it since part of the reason I am confused is why it sees these coordinate variables as different from temperature..

Here is information about the dataset.. I guess the coordinates are float64

```
Coordinates:
    time        datetime64[ns] ...
    step        timedelta64[ns] ...
    surface     float64 ...
  * latitude    (latitude) float64 25.0 25.25 25.5 25.75 ... 54.5 54.75 55.0
  * longitude   (longitude) float64 235.0 235.2 235.5 ... 294.5 294.8 295.0
    valid_time  datetime64[ns] ...
Data variables:
    t           (latitude, longitude) float32 ...
```

The reason why i am asking this question is because I am trying to simply subset data based on latitude/longitude

```
GFS3 = GFS3[(GFS3["longitude"]==280.25) & (GFS3["lat"]==40)]
```

But when I run it I get the error

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\kevin\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 77, in <module>
    GFS3 = GFS3[(GFS3["longitude"]==280.25) & (GFS3["lat"]==40)]

  File "C:\Users\kevin\anaconda3\envs\flight\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3505, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "C:\Users\kevin\anaconda3\envs\flight\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3623, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err

KeyError: 'longitude'
```

Comment: sorry - it's really not clear to me what you're asking. can you show what you've tried as code [not images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and show the error or behavior you're seeing and what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

## Pandas MultiIndex

From what I see, `GFS3 = ds2.to_dataframe(dim_order=None)` returns a dataframe with a MultiIndex `(latitude, longitude)` (that's why you see only one value of `latitude` for multiple values of `longitude`).

Since you are indexing on a MultiIndex and not on columns, the syntax is different ([doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index)):

```
GFS3.loc[(40, 280.25)]
```

should return what you are looking for.

## Xarray Dataset

I would also suggest to use directly `xarray`'s capabilities.

```
ds2.sel(latitude=40, longitude=280.25)
```

will return a new dataset with the desired location only (you can also use `ds.isel(...)` for index-based indexing.